Loop Though Access Table and Send Email with Related Data for Each Individual Sales Person
I have an Access DB table with 28 rows of sales persons with their respective emails and sales data.  I need to loop through the table and create one Excel file for each salesperson and then send an email with their respective Excel file. I borrowed the following code but not getting the desired results.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.
Public Sub SendRptDSM()

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM DropShipReportDSM"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            DoCmd.OpenReport "DropShipReportDSM", acViewPreview, , "DSMKey = " & rs!DSMKey
            DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "DropShipReportDSM", acFormatXLSX, rs![DSMEmail], , , "subject text here", "message text here", True
            DoCmd.Close acReport, "reportname", acSaveNo
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub

When I execute the code I would have expected a new email with an attached Excel file for each sales person but what I got was a blank report.

Is DSMKey text, or numeric?

In addition to checking what Tim mentioned above, have you validated that there are no nulls or blanks for DSMemail or DSMkeys in the recordset?
It's really easy to overlook this part, but with a loop it's critical.
Mark
